# How to make custom progressBar's background to transparent?

Tags: android

Got my custom progressBar here:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="25dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="#222222"
            android:startColor="#222222" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="25dip" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:endColor="#b32730"
                android:startColor="#aa2226" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

I would like to set the background to a little transparent.

I heard i can make transpernt colors by 8 digit color codes like this:

#00123123 is the fully transparent and #ff123123 is the fully opaque, but nothing changes, i tried it many times.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alpha level goes last. You're writing #AARRGGBB while it actually is #RRGGBBAA where AA is the alpha level